# Hive error - Select * from table ;

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I created one external table in hive which was successfully created.

```
create external table load_tweets(id BIGINT,text STRING)
     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
     LOCATION '/user/cloudera/data/tweets_raw';
```

But, when I did:

```
hive> select * from load_tweets;
```

I got the below error:

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5dfb0646; line: 1, column: 2]**

Please suggest me how to fix this. Is it the twitter o/p file which was created using flume was corrupted or anything else?

Comment: Please provide data example as well.

Comment: You don't have valid JSON data

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do two additional things.

1) Put data into the file (perhaps using INSERT).  Or maybe it's already there.  In either case, you'll then need to

2) from Hive, `msck repair table load_tweets;`

For Hive tables, the schema and other meta-information about the data is stored in what's called the Hive Metastore -- it's actually a relational database under the covers.  When you perform operations on Hive tables created without the `LOCATION` keyword (that is, internal, not external tables), the Hive will automatically update the metastore.

But most Hive use-cases cause data to be appended to files that are updated using other processes, and thus external tables are common.  If new partitions are created externally, before you can query them with Hive you need to force the metastore to sync with the current state of the data using `msck repair table <tablename>;`.

Comment: - Please edit your answer , `msck repair` is required only for adding new partitions in metastore for a table. Not for data in non-partitioned table

Comment: Thanks; I have clarified.  Documentation seems clear on this, but my experience has been that Hive doesn't appear to even recognize new data added externally (e.g. flume, `hdsf -put`, etc.).  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: np :) , you can also  use `analyze table`  for any metadata update if not reflected automatically on hive tables.